# Invalid stream header when consuming messages from RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jms

we use [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) as a messaging broker. To communicate with queues we use JMS implementation of [RabbitMQ JMS client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq.jms/rabbitmq-jms/1.11.2). We use JMS client for both producer and consumer. The issue is with the consumer when trying to read the messages from the queue. it throws the following exception. Please let me know how to resolve this.

**Error Messages**

```
    com.rabbitmq.jms.util.RMQJMSException: invalid stream header: 68656C6C
    at com.rabbitmq.jms.client.RMQMessage.fromMessage(RMQMessage.java:1128) ~[rabbitmq-jms-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.jms.client.RMQMessage.convertJmsMessage(RMQMessage.java:901) ~[rabbitmq-jms-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.jms.client.RMQMessage.convertMessage(RMQMessage.java:895) ~[rabbitmq-jms-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.jms.client.MessageListenerConsumer.handleDelivery(MessageListenerConsumer.java:154) ~[rabbitmq-jms-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149) [amqp-client-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104) [amqp-client-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 68656C6C
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.rabbitmq.jms.util.WhiteListObjectInputStream.<init>(WhiteListObjectInputStream.java:90) ~[rabbitmq-jms-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.jms.client.RMQMessage.fromMessage(RMQMessage.java:1102) ~[rabbitmq-jms-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

**Producer.Java**

```
        RMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new RMQConnectionFactory();
                connectionFactory.setUsername("xxx");
                connectionFactory.setPassword("xxx");
                connectionFactory.setHost(xxx.xxx.xxx);

                RMQDestination jmsDestination = new RMQDestination();
                jmsDestination.setAmqp(true);
                jmsDestination.setQueue(true);
                jmsDestination.setAmqpExchangeName("");
                jmsDestination.setAmqpRoutingKey(queueName);
                jmsDestination.setDestinationName(queueName);
                jmsDestination.setAmqpQueueName(queueName);

    try (javax.jms.Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {

                    connection.start();
                    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(jmsDestination);
                    TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage("My message");
                    msg.setJMSType("TextMessage");
                    producer.send(msg);
        }
```

**Consumer.Java**

```
 Connection connection = null;
    RMQConnectionFactory factory = new RMQConnectionFactory();
                factory.setHost(GTAFConfig.MESSAGE_QUEUE_HOST_IP.value());
                factory.setUsername("xxx");
                factory.setPassword("xxx");

                if (connection == null)
                    connection = factory.createConnection();

                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                Queue queue = session
                        .createQueue(QueueRegistry.getQueueName("queue name");
                MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
                consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
                connection.start();

    @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {


            try {
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    System.out.println("Successfully receievedt message,msg id:" +message.getJMSMessageID());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to read back the message, you would need to set up an RMQDestination in your consumer, like in your producer

Like this:

```
RMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new RMQConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/");
connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");

RMQDestination jmsDestination = new RMQDestination();
jmsDestination.setAmqp(true);
jmsDestination.setAmqpQueueName("rabbitQueueName");

Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
RMQMessageConsumer consumer = (RMQMessageConsumer)session.createConsumer(jmsDestination);
```

(Grabbed this code from a dev on the RabbitMQ JMS Client here
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/Zbcp9WL-vUM)